# Issues with a Loop Exiting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an "if or" statement to compare cells in six rows (A1 compare with B1, B1 to C1, so on and so forth). Somehow my if or statement does not seem to be working. Can someone help and check my code please?

```
Dim I As Byte

I = 2



If Range("b" & I) - Range("c" & I) > 0 _
Or Range("c" & I) - Range("d" & I) > 0 _
Or Range("d" & I) - Range("e" & I) > 0 _
Or Range("e" & I) - Range("f" & I) > 0 _
Or Range("f" & I) - Range("g" & I) > 0 _
Then

Range("h" & I).Value = y


Else

Range("h" & I).Value = N
End If

I = I + 1
```

Follow Up, the problem is now solved, thanks for everyone's help!

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheet1.Activate

Dim i As Long
Dim theColumn As Long
Dim LastCell As Long
LastCell = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
i = 1
Do

i = i + 1
For theColumn = 2 To 6
    Dim higher As Boolean
    higher = Cells(i, theColumn).Value - Cells(i, theColumn + 1).Value > 0
    If higher Then Exit For
Next

Cells(i, "H").Value = higher
If i = LastCell Then Exit Do
Loop

MsgBox "Analysis Completed"
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what are you expecting the results to be?

Comment: Please share some sample data that you would expect to pass or fail this test so we can help out. Right now this says "If any of these conditions is true, then set `Range("H" & I).Value` to variable Y". Is that what you want?

Comment: This may be more of a personal preference, but when I'm performing multiple operations as you are I tend to (over)use parenthesis just to keep myself straight. I'm not saying this is your problem, but I'd write each part of your comparisons as `((Range("b" & I) - Range("c" & I)) > 0)`. One additional thing I will note is that your `Range` reference is referring to the currently active worksheet (which might not be what you want). So [fully qualify](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references) your references.

Comment: Are you sure that `Or` is what you want and not `And`

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to loop without any code that actually loops.

Comment: Why not provide values from the cells in `B2:G2` for which your code doesn't act as expected? All you have told us is that it somehow doesn't seem to be working without telling us what "working" consists of.

Comment: why not a formula, put this in H2: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:F2>C2:G2)),"Y","N")` and copy down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a little easier to digest:

```
Dim theColumn as Long

For theColumn = 2 to 6 'compare columns B-G
    Dim higher as Boolean
    higher = Cells(I,theColumn).Value - Cells(I,theColumn+1).Value > 0
    If higher Then Exit For
Next

Cells(I,"H").Value = higher
'Cells(I,"H").Value = Iif(higher,"Y","N")
```

Comment: in vba true = is negative and as such it is returning false positives

Comment: you will want: `higher = IIf(Cells(2, theColumn) - Cells(2, theColumn + 1) > 0, True, False)`.  Also you have a typo.  `Than` should be `Then`

Comment: thanks for picking up my trash @ScottCraner. I meant to add the > 0 and forgot.

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman, many thanks for your solution. However, your code will only perform the test for one row of data, mine has over 900 rows and I am trying to add a "do loop" to repeat this test for all the rows (weeks). Are there any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @KaileiZhang - You're original question as written is different than what it is now; which is not fair to people answering your or looking for a solution. In the context of your edited question, this answer makes little sense. Your original question pre-supposed a looper of `i`. Placing this code directly in the loop will loop through each iteration of `i`, *if you set up the loop correctly* (hint: you're edited question does not loop correctly!). I suggest reverting your question back to the original and asking a new question if you have a different one after searching online for how to loop.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Hi, thanks for reminding, I have reposted my original question, and I have come up with a solution, I put the do loop at the wrong place, now the code can do what I need it to do. Thanks again for the big help !!

Comment: @KaileiZhang - glad you got it solved. its best practice to mark any answer that solved your question as answered so others know moving forward.